# How to correctly build a list of tiles in a for loop?

Tags: java

I'm working at a turn-based strategy game for school and the playing field consists of a grid 8x8. So there are 64 tiles in a map. For now i'm testing to generate a map apart from the GUI. My grid is x,y based, so the first tile will be (1,1), the second (2,1), the ninth(1,2) .. 64th (8,8).

My idea was to generate a map, that is a list of tiles, in a for loop, like this:

```
// GENERATE MAP
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if(x != 9) {
            Tile tile = new Tile(x, y, null);
            tiles.add(tile);
            x++;
        }
        else {
            x = 1 ;
            y++;
            Tile tile = new Tile(x, y, null);
            tiles.add(tile);
        }
    }
```

The problem is when i am unit testing the map, my expected x,y values are not the same as in the generated map.

```
assertEquals(64, tiles.size());
assertEquals(new Point(2,1), tiles.get(1).getPos());
assertEquals(new Point(8,1), tiles.get(7).getPos());
assertEquals(new Point(1,2), tiles.get(8).getPos());
assertEquals(new Point(8,8), tiles.get(63).getPos());

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :java.awt.Point[x=8,y=8]
Actual   :java.awt.Point[x=1,y=8]
<Click to see difference>
```

Tile 63 must be the last tile(8,8) but it isn't. Can someone help me out here?

Besides this problem, my idea was to later set terrain on certain tiles, with tiles.get(4).setTerrain("Tree"); etc. Is this way of creating a map with tiles a good start or am i working in the wrong direction? Later we will bind it to the GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: x will never be another thing than 1 :)

Comment: I imagine this is a great opportunity to step through the code in a debugger as it executes and observe what's happening to `x` over time.

Comment: I did, and x is really incrementing, but i don't want to debug until the 64th tile :(

Comment: Ok, here is the issue:  pretend that we're looping over a 3x3 square:

x=1, y=1 --
x=2, y=1 --
x=3, y=1 --
x=1, y=2 -- 
x=1, y=2.  That is, you end up adding a duplicate element after you reset the value of x.  But that being said, follow the advice of using a nested for loop instead :)

Comment: @muzzlator public Tile(int x, int y, Terrain terrain) { Point pos = new Point(x,y); this.pos = pos; this.terrain = terrain; }

Comment: @Maikkeyy: `"but i don't want to debug until the 64th tile"` - That shows a pretty serious lack of effort on your part.  64 iterations of a loop is not a lot.  It's likely you may even spot the error long before that.  Debugging is an important skill, and this is a good chance to practice it.

Comment: @muzzlator you're right, but when i remove the tiles.add in the else block, the whole size of the tiles list was 58 or something, not 64. So that confused me. David hmm, you have got a point there, fair enough.

Comment: @Maikkeyy it's a logical problem, i'm sure you can fix it now that you see what's going wrong. Break the logic down into two parts, the adding of the tile, and the update of the variables. It'll be simpler to follow. Or use the nested for loop..

Comment: Your last paragraph ("Is this way of creating a map with tiles a good start...?") should be a separate question.  It would be off-topic as "too broad" on Stack Overflow, but might be [on-topic at Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: A suggestion:  If it looks like you'll frequently be converting from two-dimensional (x, y) format to your one-dimensional 0-through-63 index and back, create two static methods named something like `toIndex(int, int)` and `toXY(int)` so you have the logic in (almost) one place.  (Off-by-one errors are even _less_ fun when they are hiding in 17 different places.)  Maybe create an immutable `Coords` or `XY` class with two `int` fields (`x` and `y`), an `indexOf` object method, and a sensible `toString` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested loop to get your x and y values.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        //do something with x and y here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use nested for loops..

```
for(int i = 1; i<=8; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j<=8; j++){
       // now see the values of i and j here.
       // you can use i and j to get what you want.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I think you should do it this way but this teaches an important programming concept which is that of decoupling logic that shouldn't be coupled. Here is a similar solution to the one you asked about, but in a much more obviously correct style:

```
// Initialise variables at initial position
int x = 1;
int y = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    // Add tile.
    tiles.add(new Tile(x, y, null));

    // Update position.
    x++;
    if (x == 9) {
        x = 1;
        y++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's indeed a more obvious way to face this problem. I'll test it as soon as possible for my own sake. But i mark the answer of using nested loops as accepted, because that seems like more efficient code. Much thanks for your help!